# CSS тень на соседний блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать тень шапки так, чтобы она была на всех блоках ниже, которые стоят вплотную?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы приложили хотя бы картинку как должно быть, потому что не очень понятно, что вам нужно получить.

Comment: вероятно нужно блоку задать z-index... хотя без кода не очень понятен вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блоку который отбрасывает тень нужно задать

`position: relative;
 z-index:999999;`